# DQN whole episode experience

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I was trying DQN with a simple card game just to prove my understanding of DQN. The training went fine and the agent was able to play the best card for the current step, but what made the agent poor when it comes to the final game result that the agent doesn’t keep the good cards for future steps. This makes scenes since the training is happening on each step and not the whole game. And the memory reply take random steps and not sequence steps.

How can I enhance the DQN to understand the whole episode and not only step by step learning?